# Angularjs approach

Tags: angularjs

Form:

First Name (text box) Last Name (text box)

Once the form is submitted, I need to use API - https://beta.test.com/api

The documentation says -

"POST /user will add the details to system and generates a user ID which would be returned."

After I receive user ID in response, I need to call another endpoint -

"POST /user/metadata will fetch the metadata for a previously added user."

I have to build this in Angularjs. What should be my approach? Do you have any tutorials which I can look at?

I did some code but it gave me - "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I have checked on server and the API already has cross domain allowed for all.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the answer to 2 parts - how to send chain of calls and how to avoif the CORS error.

### 1. how to chain multiple async calls

### Callbacks

You send 2 calls one after another -

```
var userParams = {
firstname: '',
lastname: ''
}

$http.get('user', userParams).
    success(function(data) {
        $http.get('/user/metadata', {user_id: data}).

        success(function(data) {
            //metadata is here
        }).
        error(function(err) {
            //somethine bad in meta data
        }
    }).
    error(function(err) {
         //something bad with user creation
    });
```

### 2. How to avoid CORS error

This problem is forced by your browser (as the server allow the income)

I use the [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) to avoid this error